# Subscript out of range for If function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a payroll application and I keep getting this message when trying to do an if function for a VBA script.

Its the first line of the If statement that is giving me a hard time.

```
Sub PayPeriod()
    If Sheets("sheet30").Range("e17") = "1" Then 'ERROR HERE
        Sheets("Week 1").Select
    ElseIf Sheets("sheet30").Range("e17") = "2" Then
        Sheets("Week 2").Select
    ElseIf Sheets("sheet30").Range("e17") = "3" Then
        Sheets("Week 3").Select
    ElseIf Sheets("sheet30").Range("e17") = "4" Then
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: check whether your workbook really has sheet "sheet30" and also try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet30").Range("e17")`

Comment: It is worksheet 30, and I just tried that line and I'm getting the same result

Comment: what do you mean `It is worksheet 30`? it's its number or name?

Answer (score 0):

Try using variables and declare them properly. You need to qualify the sheet location. Declare variables at the top, assign them the desired values once and then use the variable in your code. This way, if sheet names or cell references change, you can quickly adjust the macro in just one place. (I've left the `.Select` statement in the example, but note that you hardly ever need to select elements to work with them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PayPeriod()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet30")
Set rng = ws.Range("E17")

If rng = "1" Then
   ws.Range("Week1").Select

    [rest of your code]

End Sub
```